# Count the number of lines, matching a pattern, but only the first occurence

Tags: python, bash, count, grep, unique

I have a file with multiple lines and various content. Some line start with a specific pattern, that may reoccur. E.g.

```
some line
some line
this: idA001 text
this: idA002 text
some line
this: idB001 text
this: idA001 text
this: idA002 text
this: idC001 text
...
```

I'd like to count every first occurrence of `this: id*`..

If I use `cat file | grep "this: " | wc -l` I count every occurrence.. Do I need to write a script, that first filters for the line then eliminates duplicates, or is this possible in a one-liner bash command?
If a script is required I'd prefer Python or Bash..

Comment: So is 4 the correct answer?

Comment: correct. sorry i didn't state that in the question.

Comment: `sort < file | uniq | grep "this: " | wc -l`

Comment: As a side note, you pretty much never need `cat file | foo`; just `foo < file` does the same thing, more simply and more efficiently.

Comment: And if you had `this: idC001 other text` - is that unique or not... (ie, is that now still 4, or now 5?)

Comment: `this: idC001 other text` as for now will never occur `this: id* text` describes the line of interest and contains nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this in a bash one-liner:

```
sort < file | uniq | grep "this: " | wc -l
```

The [`uniq`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html) command removes repeated lines.

But we want to filter out duplicate lines that aren't necessarily adjacent, so we first [`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html).

The rest is the same as your original command.

With more recent *nix systems (which I think includes any system you're likely to care about), you can combine the `sort` and `uniq` calls into a single `sort -u`. Also, as jm666 pointed out, [`grep -c`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) outputs a count of matched lines instead of the matched lines, so you don't need `wc`. So the whole thing becomes:

```
sort -u < file | grep -c "this: "
```

One last thing: If you only want lines that start with `this:`, as opposed to lines that contain it anywhere, you can use the `^` special character in your grep expression, which only matches the start of a line, like so:

```
sort -u < file | grep -c "^this: "
```

Comment: I had extracting the `id` to be counted separately from the rest of the text, which since I already had it open for Python I've [put here](https://gist.github.com/joncle/19944eeb2a25cc597c09) - but that's easily done using this approach and using `grep` appropriately :) Less memory intensive using the *nix tools approach

Comment: This might be very useful to me after all! Thank you very much.

Comment: @JonClements: Of course the Python version has the advantage of working on Windows (but then I can't remember the last time I used a Windows machine without installing either msys or cygwin or tossing the machine out a window, so that rarely matters to me…).

Comment: you cold to use `grep -c` and not need the `wc` ;)

Comment: @jm666: Thanks. Don't know how I forgot that…

Comment: `uniq` and `sort -u` won't help if a pattern can match multiple unique lines e.g., `this: id*` pattern matches both `this: id` and `this: idd` lines.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Something starting with `this: idd` would either be impossible, or distinct from the same thing starting with `this: id`, in his input, so the fact that `sort -u` will leave it to be counted as distinct by `grep` is not a problem, it's exactly what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
awk '/^this:/ && !seen[$0]++ {a++} END {print a}' file
4
```

It will count how many unique line starting with `this:`

Answer (score 1):

in single line  we can do like this

```
len({i for i in file if i.startswith('this :id')})
```

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension inside a call to `set`. Either use a set comprehension (if you're on Python 2.7+), or use a generator expression inside a call to `set`. Otherwise, you're wastefully building a list just to build a set out of it.

Comment: Also, don't call `readlines()`; that _also_ wastefully builds a list. Just use `for i in file`.

Comment: Probably also should be a `if i.startswith('this :id')` going by the OP's *Some line start with a specific pattern*

Comment: @JonClements thanks to all for correcting my answer :)

Comment: @JonClements: That is definitely an improvement, but considering that the OP considered `grep "this: "` to be part of a valid solution (except for the duplicates issue) I'm not sure it's a _necessary_ one.

Comment: And you probably want to take the `len` of the `set` - not its `sum` :)

Answer (score -1):

This will be simple solution:

```
my_words = ['this: id']
a = set()
with open('got.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
    if any(word in line for word in my_words):
            a.add(line)
print len(a)
```

What I have done:  I have written the lines containing 'this: id' in a set. Since set only contains unique values , your purpose is solved. This is one of the practical use of sets.

Comment: Why overcomplicate it with that list of one word? (Also, calling it a "word" seems a little misleading…) And other than being more verbose and indented incorrectly, what does this have over sundar's solution?

Comment: He said bash or python. Bash solution was already given so I provided python. Nothing wrong in knowing an alternative.

Comment: Sundar's solution is also in Python. And his is working, idiomatic, concise, and readable. All you've done is unpacked his comprehension, added more complexity that does nothing useful, and broken it.